# How to add attribute ID in drop down for laravel blade template system?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel and to get drop down in view, I am using `{{ Form::select('state', array(<values>)); }}` and this is result in a dropdown with an array of values mentioned in  . It `name` attribute value will be "state" since it is mentioned in Form. But how to add `ID` attribute to access it using jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pass the extra attributes in 4th paremeter, third is default selection option which is null in your case.

try this

```
{{ Form::select('state', array(<values>), null,array('id' => 'selectID')); }}
```

Comment: I want select tag without any options. On even I will fill it with ajax. So in such cases is that OK to leave 2nd parameter blank? I mean array with NO values